# связь между таблицами (одна за другой), проблема с if & else - говорит, что нет объекта | поместить пользователя в несколько таблиц при регистрации

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Краткое описание проблемы:**

У меня есть две таблицы: компании и персоналии, обе связаны идентификацией, однако мне нужно, чтобы зарегистрированный пользователь в компаниях также регистрировался в личностях, потому что я получу его имя там, но это не произойдет автоматически, в конечном итоге разоблачение приложения, потому что мне нужно создать по одному вручную, мне нужно, чтобы имена пользователей, зарегистрированных в таблице компании, также присутствовали в таблице личных данных, правильно связанных между собой.

---

Мне нужно знать, существует ли представление или нет, потому что имя файла происходит из базы данных, я сделал, если показать что-то еще, если ничего нет, когда его нет в базе данных, он говорит: **Trying to get property 'index_company' of non-object** (index_company - имя столбца)

Я зашел в Google и увидел, что на некоторых форумах говорят, что я не могу сделать это таким образом, потому что это не семантическое или что-то еще, хотя оно работает, когда оно существует, поэтому я изменил его на значение, подобное 0, что они и указали Гамбиарра работал, пока значение не было включено в таблицу, а затем предоставил следующее: **Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**

**controller**

```
public function searchByName($name)
    {
        $company = Company::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();
        $personality = DB::table('personalities')->where('name', $name)->first();
        $home_cp = DB::table('personalities')->select('index_company')->where('name', $name)->first();  

        return view('company.base.index', compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'home_cp'));
    }
```

- что он делает: получить имя URL (app.com/company/name) и проверить, есть ли пользователь с таким именем, если он существует, сопоставить таблицы с конкретными данными этого пользователя; В этом случае он получает значение из столбца index_company.

**index.blade.php**

```
@if (view()->exists("company.base.$home_cp->index_company"))
    {{ view("company.base.$home_cp->index_company", compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'home_cp')) }} 
@else
    {{ view('company.base.not_company', compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'home_cp')) }}
@endif
```

- **Что он делает:** Помните, что index_company ссылается на имя файла; Проверьте, существует этот файл или нет, если я не существую, остановите скрипт и просто запустите то, что внутри @else

где ошибка?

Если это возможно, я опубликовал пример, чтобы попытаться поймать, не нашел ничего об этом в документации, далеко не спорно, а не для целей вы хотите.

Извините, если в какой-то момент я был груб, это не было моим намерением, я все еще учусь, я не знаю всех слов, поправьте меня, если я что-то пропустил.

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: увидеть ответ, возможно уточнить вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ, который решил мою проблему, дал [ШАЗ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/73/shaz) в испанской версии stackoverflow

> Проблема не в том, если проблема в том, что когда имя представления не
>   существует в базе данных Eloquent, оно возвращает нуль вместо объекта,
>   поэтому $ home_cp-> index_company не будет работать и будет
>   отображаться первая ошибка. как вы упоминаете.
>
> **решение**
>
> Есть много решений этой типичной проблемы, я объясню самое простое (с
>   моей точки зрения):
>
> Вы можете проверить тип ответа, который предоставляет запрос:
>
> ```
> $home_cp = DB::table('personalities')
>               ->select('index_company')
>               ->whereName($name)
>               ->first();
>
> $viewName = is_null($home_cp) ? 'not_company' : $home_cp->index_company;
>
> @if (view()->exists("company.base.$viewName"))
>   {{ view("company.base.$viewName", compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'home_cp')) }}
> @else
>   {{ view('company.base.not_company', compact('company', 'name', 'personality', 'home_cp')) }}
> @endif
> ```
>
> ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Это базовая реализация, объясняющая решение, но, среди
>   прочего, можно улучшить первоначальную проверку, как называется
>   визуализация.

ссылка на вопрос: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/304081/relaci%c3%b3n-de-tablaum-a-um-problema-con-if-else-dice-que-no-es-un-objeto/304149#304149